# Xcode 14.2 producing multiple info.plist

Tags: ios, xcode, plist

I have a `info.plist` file I want to use inside my project.
The `Location` is set to `Relative to project`
The `target membership` is checked

I get this error

```
Multiple commands produce '...appname.app/Info.plist'
```

Under that I have two children items of that error

```
Target 'targetname' (project 'targetname') has copy command from 'my own folder/Info.plist' to '/Users/.../Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/project.../Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/appname.app/Info.plist'


Target 'targetname' (project 'projectname') has process command with output '/Users/.../Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/.../Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/appname.app/Info.plist'
```

I tried editing the other info.plist directly, it just gets regenerated

I tried deleting the derived data folder, it just gets regenerated

I added the info.plist to `copy bundle resources` there are no duplicates

There are no duplicates in `compile sources` either

Could it be something with
**project.pbxproj**

```
// !$*UTF8*$!
{
    archiveVersion = 1;
    classes = {
    };
    objectVersion = 56;
    objects = {

/* Begin PBXBuildFile section */


        75B28283299B83B10087A029 /* Info.plist in Resources */ = {isa = PBXBuildFile; fileRef = 75B28282299B83B10087A029 /* Info.plist */; };


        75E959AD299943800053FCFD /* SettingsModal.swift in Sources */ = {isa = PBXBuildFile; fileRef = 75E959AC299943800053FCFD /* SettingsModal.swift */; };
        75F816D829980B1E002062A9 /* appname.swift in Sources */ = {isa = PBXBuildFile; fileRef = 75F816D729980B1E002062A9 /* appname.swift */; };
        75F816DA29980B1E002062A9 /* ContentView.swift in Sources */ = {isa = PBXBuildFile; fileRef = 75F816D929980B1E002062A9 /* ContentView.swift */; };
        75F816E129980B1F002062A9 /* Persistence.swift in Sources */ = {isa = PBXBuildFile; fileRef = 75F816E029980B1F002062A9 /* Persistence.swift */; };
        75F816E429980B1F002062A9 /* appname.xcdatamodeld in Sources */ = {isa = PBXBuildFile; fileRef = 75F816E229980B1F002062A9 /* projectname.xcdatamodeld */; };
/* End PBXBuildFile section */

/* Begin PBXFileReference section */
        75B28282299B83B10087A029 /* Info.plist */ = {isa = PBXFileReference; fileEncoding = 4; lastKnownFileType = text.plist.xml; name = Info.plist; path = projectname/Info.plist; sourceTree = SOURCE_ROOT; };
    ...
    GENERATE_INFOPLIST_FILE = YES;
```

Any help is welcome, thanks

Comment: Have you tried `GENERATE_INFOPLIST_FILE = NO;`?

Comment: When I set it to "NO" then I get "Cannot code sign because the target does not have an Info.plist file and one is not being generated automatically. Apply an Info.plist file to the target using the INFOPLIST_FILE build setting or generate one automatically by setting the GENERATE_INFOPLIST_FILE build setting to YES (recommended)."

I also recreated the whole project from scratch and the errors persist, I'll figure it out eventually.

Comment: [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/DeveloperTools/Reference/XcodeBuildSettingRef/1-Build_Setting_Reference/build_setting_ref.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003931-CH3-SW68). Have a look here on how to set a file instead of generating one.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look into the "Copy Bundle Resources" in Build Phase for a reference to the Info.plist file. It does not need to be in that list, because Xcode handles that creation of the final Info.plist separately during the build.

Just remove it and it will fix the issue

Answer (score -1):

Temporary fix

INFOPLIST_KEY_NSFaceIDUsageDescription = "This app uses Face ID for authentication purposes.";